# How to get the Id of Passed html element Using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy

I have code in my list page something like this:

```
 <g:each in="${clientTripInstanceList}" status="i" var="clientTripInstance">
     <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}" id="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
         <td onclick="show_view('${clientTripInstance.id}')" class = "td_link">${fieldValue(bean: clientTripInstance, field: "number")}</td>
         <td onclick="show_view('${clientTripInstance.id}')" class = "td_link">${fieldValue(bean: clientTripInstance, field: "client")}</td>

      </tr>
</g:each>
```

now

```
function show_view(trip_id){
   var rowId =           // get the id of the row

 }
```

from this function I need to get the id of the table row which is specified above. How do I get that using jQuery? I tried this:

```
var rowId = (this).attr("id");
```

which is not working at all. Note the point that I have defined id in `<tr>` not in `<td>` where I'm calling the function, and the function is defined in other page.

Comment: var rowId =$(this).attr("id"); the dollar sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer the table cell you click in show_view(), you can pass a 'this' parameter to the function, try this:

```
<td onclick="show_view(this, '${clientTripInstance.id}')" class = "td_link">${fieldValue(bean: clientTripInstance, field: "number")}</td>

function show_view(dom, trip_id) {
    var rowId = $(dom).parent().attr("id");
}
```

Comment: One more help please! How to get the id of next <tr> using jquery?

Comment: you could get answered easily by checking the API: http://api.jquery.com/browser/

Answer (score 2):

You had forgotten the dollar sign :(

```
var rowId = $(this).attr("id");
```

**EDIT**

```
<g:each in="${clientTripInstanceList}" status="i" var="clientTripInstance">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}" id="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
        <td id="${clientTripInstance.id}" onclick="show_view('${clientTripInstance.id}')" class= "td_link">${fieldValue(bean: clientTripInstance, field: "number")}</td>
        <td onclick="show_view('${clientTripInstance.id}')" class= "td_link">${fieldValue(bean: clientTripInstance, field: "client")}</td>
    </tr>
</g:each>

function show_view(trip_id){
    var $this = $('#' + trip_id);
    var row_id = $this.parent().attr('id');
}
```

Comment: i have  function show_view(trip_id){
   var rowId =           // get the id of the row

 } at different page not in the same page where i'm calling that function

Comment: Let me know if my edit helps. I added an id attribute to the first td which I think will be necessary to access it later.

Comment: i have done it with diffrent way                          <td onclick="show_view(this,'${clientTripInstance.id}')"  id ="myid" class = "td_link">${fieldValue(bean: clientTripInstance, field: "number")}</td> and then changed function like ... function show_view(element,trip_id){
   var rowId =    $(element).closest("tr").attr("id");    

 }

Comment: One more help please! How to get the id of next <tr> using jquery?

Comment: From the tr before it? $('#foo').next(); where #foo is a tr. This will return `undefined` if there is not another sibling after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
var rowId = this.id
```

This is just javascript, not jQuery

Comment: +1 Sometimes the straightforward javascript way is the best way - although in this case 'this' is a little ambiguous.

Comment: its giving undefined, i have  function show_view(trip_id){
   var rowId =           // get the id of the row

 } at different page not in the same page where i'm calling that function

Comment: so can u suggest the exact answer?

Comment: One more help please! How to get the id of next <tr> using jquery?